# volley - blank error response, wont parse any of my pages

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

http://pastebin.com/M95G9kb3

Everytime i start the cue on my page i get the following: '[1] 5.onErrorResponse: Error: '
with NO error message. and yet it works happily on a yahoo pipes json page, and i cant quite understand why, i presume somethings wrong with my json but i can spot anything?

```
   mRequestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(acc);
        final String URL = "x";
     // pass second argument as "null" for GET requests
     JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                       // parseJSON(response);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            });
      mRequestQueue.add(req);
```

Comment: Where does PHP come into it?

Comment: the json is outputted with json_encode so i thought that might be a cause